# error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘int *’ and ‘int *’)

Tags: c

app is getting number and make square with numbers which come from user then it counts them like :

```
2 3 4

4 5 7

2 6 8
```

then is count (2+5+8)-(4-5-2) and print it on screen

```
error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘int *’ and ‘int *’)
```

for the expression:

```
total2+=numbers[counter1]+numbers[counter2];
```

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
      int scale;

      scanf("%d",&scale);
      int clone1=scale;
      int clone2=scale;
      int numbers[scale][scale];//scale of square we enter
      int counter1=0;
      int counter2=0;

      while(clone2>0)
      {
        while(clone1>0)
        {
          scanf("%d",&numbers[counter1][counter2]);
          counter2++;
          clone1--;
        }
        clone1=scale;
        counter2=0;
        counter1++;
        clone2--;
      }

      clone1=scale;
      clone2=scale;
      counter1=0;
      int total1=0;

      while(clone1>0)
      {
        total1= numbers[counter1] + numbers[counter1] + total1;
        clone1--;
        counter1++;
      }
      int total2=0;
      counter1=0;
      counter2=scale;
      clone1=scale;

      while(clone1>0)
      {
        total2= numbers[counter1] + numbers[counter2] + total2;
        counter1++;
        counter2--;
      }
      printf("%d",total1-total2);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your code could do with a little indentation love..

Comment: `numbers` is a 2D array. What do you expect `numbers[counter1] + numbers[counter1]` to do?

Comment: _Variable length arrays_ like `int numbers[scale][scale];` are not supported in standard C++.  Instead, there is `std::vector` (which you'd use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for a vector of vectors of ints).

Comment: The example `(2+5+8)-(4-5-2)` is not what your code looks like it is attempting to do.  Is the example correct or did you intend `(2+5+8)-(4+5+2)`?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it right you wish to compute the det of a square matrix, in which case you should change `total1= numbers[counter1] + numbers[counter1] + total1;` to `numbers[counter1][counter1] + total1;`
and `total2= numbers[counter1] + numbers[counter2] + total2;` to `total2= numbers[counter1][counter2] + total2;`
In your version you were actually trying to add the row pointers instead of an the value at the counter positions. 
in your last loop you also want to decrease clone1 or it will stay in the loop forever as it never hits 0.

Answer (score 0):

`numbers[counter1]` and `numbers[counter2]` each refer to a *row* integers and of length `scale`.  The *row* has type `int*` (pointer to the row of integers).  The `+` operand operates on *single* integers (`int`).

To fix your code you need:

```
total1 += numbers[counter1][counter1] ;
```

and

```
total2 += numbers[counter1][counter2] ;
```

I think - it is hard to determine if there may be other issues since you appear to be making a simple problem complicated.  I suggest:

```
int leading_diagonal = 0 ;
int trailing_diagonal = 0 ;
for( int i = 0; i < scale; i++ )
{
    leading_diagonal += numbers[i][i] ;
    trailing_diagonal += numbers[i][scale-1-i] ;
}

printf( "%d\n", leading_diagonal - trailing_diagonal ) ;
```

However while your example requires `(2+5+8)-(4-5-2)` your code appears to be an attempt to evaluate `(2+5+8)-(4+5+2)`. If your example is in fact correct and what you intended, then:

```
int leading_diagonal = numbers[0][0] ;
int trailing_diagonal = numbers[0][scale-1] ;
for( int i = 1; i < scale; i++ )
{
    leading_diagonal += numbers[i][i] ;
    trailing_diagonal -= numbers[i][scale-1-i] ;
}

printf( "%d\n", leading_diagonal - trailing_diagonal ) ;
```